# Reverse for 'facebook_login' not found

Tags: django, django-templates, facebook-login, django-allauth

I keep getting:

> NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'facebook_login' not found. 'facebook_login' is not a valid view function or pattern name

when I try to use django-allauth. I have followed their documentation but I still can't figure out why I get this error.

From django-allauth documentation, I have created:

```
url
   urlpatterns = [

      ('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
   ]


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
)

 SITE_ID = 1
```

I have also added to installed apps the following:

```
 'allauth', 
 'allauth.account', 
 'allauth.socialaccount', 
 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
```

indext.html

```
 {% load socialaccount %}

<a href="{% provider_login_url 'facebook' %}">Facebook</a>
```

Comment: If you are trying to write login templates for Django application that uses allauth, you can use this file as reference. https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/templates/account/login.html

Comment: Thanks @Jaskaran.  What i am trying to do is just a simple implementation of allauth using fb.

Comment: try `<a href="{% provider_login_url "facebook" method="js_sdk" %}">Facebook Connect</a>` or `<a href="{% provider_login_url "facebook" method="oauth2" %}">Facebook OAuth2</a>` maybe?

Comment: Can you show full list of urls plese?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add allauth.urls in urls.py and it includes 'facebook_login' view.

```
path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls'))
```